# Golang CGO unable to use converted string

Tags: c, windows, go, c-strings, cgo

I'm attempting to set the title of the Windows command prompt using CGO and the windows c header:

```
// #include <windows.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Title(title string) {
  ctitle := C.CString(title)
  defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(ctitle))
  C.SetConsoleTitle(ctitle)
}
```

But at compile time, the following error occurs:

```
cannot use ctitle (type *C.char) as type *C.CHAR in argument to _Cfunc_SetConsoleTitle
```

It would seem that `C.SetConsoleTitle(ctitle)` is expecting a string of type `*C.CHAR` but `C.CString(title)` is returning `*C.char`

How should I go about converting the string to the expected type?

Comment: try to change `C.SetConsoleTitle(ctitle)` to `C.SetConsoleTitle(title.c_str())`

Comment: @LPs That doesn't seem possible `title.c_str undefined (type string has no field or method c_str)` Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, You're able to cast the pointer to an `*C.CHAR`:

```
// #include <windows.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Title(title string) {
  ctitle := unsafe.Pointer(C.CString(title))
  defer C.free(ctitle)
  C.SetConsoleTitle((*C.CHAR)(ctitle))
}
```